# ibatis sqlmapclient loading issue

Tags: xml, spring, mybatis, ibatis, sqlmap

i'm loading sqlmapclient in spring_config.xml like below

```
<bean id="sqlMapClient"
        class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocations" value="com/de/test/SqlMapConfig.xml"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

But the property is not loading sqlMapConfig.xml . and my sqlMapConfig.xml is

```
<sqlMapConfig>

<settings
cacheModelsEnabled="true"
enhancementEnabled="true"
lazyLoadingEnabled="true"
maxRequests="32"
maxSessions="10"
maxTransactions="5"
useStatementNamespaces="true"
/>

    <!--Addind Resource files -->
    <sqlMap resource="emerg_ibatis_services.xml"/>
    <sqlMap resource="external_ibatis_services.xml"/>

</sqlMapConfig>
```

Throwing Exception as below,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in class path resource [irams_de_spring_config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:716)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.bt.irams.de.test.Test.main(Test.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.<init>(SqlMapConfigParser.java:58)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.<init>(SqlMapConfigParser.java:45)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:334)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating logger for class class com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibatis.common.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:33)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.<clinit>(SqlMapClientImpl.java:40)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibatis.common.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:31)
    ... 21 more
```

What problem causes with this code? i'm using ibatis 2.3.0

Comment: It doesn't have to do with your configuration. It's something related to your logging configuration. See the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/ibatis/common/logging/LogFactory.java.html).

Comment: yes..because that configlocations property sqlmapConfig.xml is not loading..But this is proper way to load xml..i checked with Spring Doc..Can u please tell me why it's not loading?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java.html) for SqlMapClientFactoryBean. If you pay attention at the stack trace, you can see the following lines:

```
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.<init>(SqlMapConfigParser.java:58)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.<init>(SqlMapConfigParser.java:45)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:334)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:291)
```

The source code for line 334 (and few before that) in SqlMapClientFactoryBean is:

```
if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configLocations)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least 1 'configLocation' entry is required");
    }

    SqlMapClient client = null;
    SqlMapConfigParser configParser = new SqlMapConfigParser();
```

Before the source code line where SqlMapConfigParser is created (line 334 in the stack trace), there is an `if` statement that doesn't fail (otherwise you would have seen `IllegalArgumentException` instead of a `NullPointerException`). So, there is nothing wrong with `configLocations`. The problem is in iBatis' own code, loading the file isn't even reached, because of the logging setup in iBatis.

Start by debugging the initialization code: insert a break point at line 12 in [LogFactory class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/ibatis/common/logging/LogFactory.java.html) and see if there is anything wrong with the class loader used by [com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/ibatis/common/resources/Resources.java.html) and why doesn't find any of these classes from LogFactory:

```
   tryImplementation("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", "com.ibatis.common.logging.jakarta.JakartaCommonsLoggingImpl");
   tryImplementation("org.apache.log4j.Logger", "com.ibatis.common.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl");
   tryImplementation("java.util.logging.Logger", "com.ibatis.common.logging.jdk14.Jdk14LoggingImpl");
   tryImplementation("java.lang.Object", "com.ibatis.common.logging.nologging.NoLoggingImpl");
```

Maybe you have multiple iBatis jars in your classpath, or maybe you don't have iBatis in your classpath, I don't know. And it's hard to tell from the stack trace, because iBatis code hides any exceptions that might be thrown in case a class loading problem occurs:

```
try {
      Resources.classForName(testClassName);
      Class implClass = Resources.classForName(implClassName);
      logConstructor = implClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{Class.class});
} catch (Throwable t) {
}
```

Comment: inline '<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">'  is this valid dtd? this dtd still available or not? i think problem with this dtd only

Comment: Try this: `<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
    PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
`